# Solve $f'(x) = 0$ and set up a sign chart for $f'$.

Tags: derivatives

[image]

I understand how my teacher got the two $x$ values, but why didn't he solve for $e^x=0$?

I know he did

$x=0$ which is $0$

$x+2=0$ which is $-2$

so why no $e^x=0$? is there even an answer for that? I don't think there is right?

Comment: $e^x\neq 0$ for all $x$, in fact $e^x>0$ if $x$ is real.

Comment: Graph $e^x$ and see for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look closely at the definition of $e^x$ you can conclude that there is no value such that $e^x = 0$ as seen in the formula below

$$
e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}
$$
Since when k = 0, the sum will be:

$$
e^x = 1+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}
$$
Since all terms when summed together will yield a result greater than zero, there is no possible way to have any real value for $x$ such that $e^x = 0$. This is even true for any value you make x, including imaginary values of x.

Comment: @amzoti yes I edited my answer, I'm so used to putting n, quite a bad habit.

Comment: All other terms (other than the constant term) don't have to sum to something positive, but they do have to something greater than -1.